# Find the closed form from a recurrence relation using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I want to find the closed form of $$b_{n}=a_{n} - a_{n-1}, a_{0} = b_{0}$$ in terms of $A(x)$.

**Attempt:**

I first tried to rewrite as:  $b_{n+1}=a_{n+1} - a_{n}$ then I multiplied both sides by $x^{n+1}$ to get:
$$\sum_{n\geq0}b_{n+1}x^{n+1}=\sum_{n\geq0}a_{n+1}x^{n+1} - \sum_{n\geq0}a_{n}x^{n+1} $$ 
then I get:
$$B(x)= A(x) -xA(x)$$ I am not sure how to proceed from here to get the closed form.

Comment: I think you have everything possible in closed form, both $b_n$ and $B(x)$

Comment: just extract $(1-x)$ on the RHS

Comment: Be careful of your indexing. E.g. is the LHS truly $B(x)$?

Comment: @CalvinLin isn't the LHS just $B(x) - b_0$ but the RHS has $A(x) - a_0$ from the first term but they cancel since $a_0=b_0$?

Answer (score 1):

Define generating functions:

$\begin{align*}
   A(z)
       &= \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n \\
   B(z)
       &= \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n
\end{align*}$

Write your recurrence shifted, multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize resulting sums:

$\begin{align*}
   \sum_{n \ge 0} b_{n +1} z^n
       &=  \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n +1} z^n
                 -  \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n  \\
   \frac{B(z) - b_0}{z}
       &= \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} - A(z)
\end{align*}$

Solve for $B(z)$, remembering $b_0 = a_0$:

$\begin{equation*}
   B(z)
       = A(z) (1 - z)
\end{equation*}$

Answer (score 0):

In this case the use of generating functions is not useful. This will be seen by the following demonstration.

Begin with 
$$b_{n} = a_{n} - a_{n-1}, \hspace{5mm} a_{0} = b_{0}$$
and turn it into
$$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + b_{n} \hspace{5mm} a_{0} = b_{0}.$$ 
For $n=1$: $a_{1} = a_{0} + b_{1} = b_{0} + b_{1}$. Repeating the process leads to
$$a_{n} = \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_{j}.$$
It is quickly found that $a_{n} - a_{n-1} = b_{n}$ and that any generating function for $b_{n}$ equals that of $b_{n}$ by the recurrence relation. In a different manor it is determined that:
Let $$B(t) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n} \, t^{n},$$ then

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n} \, t^{n} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_{j} \, t^{n} = \sum_{n,j=0}^{\infty} b_{j} \, t^{n+j} = \frac{1}{1-t} \, B(t) \\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n-1} \, t^{n} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} b_{j} \, t^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (a_{n} - b_{n}) \, t^{n} = \left(\frac{1}{1-t} - 1\right) \, B(t) = \frac{t}{1-t} \, B(t).
\end{align} 
The recurrence equation $b_{n} = a_{n} - a_{n-1}$ leads to
$$B(t) =  \frac{1}{1-t} \, B(t) - \frac{t}{1-t} \, B(t) = B(t).$$